# iPad SplitView with UiScrollView on it shows bottom half of view in landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a simple iPad app with a UISplitView, I added a `UIScrollView` to the detail view and everything is fine in portrait orientation. When I go to landscape, the detail view only shows the bottom of the detail view and when I try to scroll to see the top of the view, it springs back down to showing just the bottom half. I am new to this and can't figure out what I am missing.

EDIT:  Turning on all 4 Struts of the `UIScrollView` in IB took care of it.

Comment: Have you tried to set the autosizing option in IB?

Comment: If you have solved your problem please post your solution as an answer below or delete your question.

Comment: I did post my solution above where it says EDIT:

Comment: Wyatt: Please post that as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning on all 4 Struts of the UIScrollView in IB took care of it.